# Let's build a tree together!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle, acrostic

It's been a while since I've posted due to being incredibly busy at work, so I've got a short and sweet Riley for anyone interested.

> Look for the infix, odious indeed,
>
> Obscenities and evil, a hex, but no e.
>
> Oddly the suffix, denotes with just three,
>
> Prefixed by back, again, it is ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer to the riddle is:

> **RECURSION**

*Look for the infix, odious indeed,*
*Obscenities and evil, a hex, but no e.*

> The infix is **CURS** - the word CURSE (which can mean both 'obscenity' and 'hex') without the 'E'.

*Oddly the suffix, denotes with just three,*

> The suffix is **ION** - this is a 3-letter acronym for 'In Other News', the phrase sometimes spoken in news broadcasts just before the 'odd' ('*oddly*') or novelty news item at the end of the bulletin...

*Prefixed by back, again, it is ?*

> The prefix is **RE**, as in 'repeat', meaning '*back, again*'... Note that this word completes the rhyme here:
>
>  *Oddly the suffix, denotes with just three,*
>  *Prefixed by back, again, it is **RE***

As for the title:

> **[Tree recursion](https://berkeley-cs61as.github.io/textbook/tree-recursion.html)** is a programming term related to looping repetitions in code. Note also that the first letters of each line spell the word '**LOOP**' - we've come full circle!